# Multivariate Adaptive Regression Splines (MARS) - Mathematica implementation?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting

Does anybody have or know of a Mathematica implementation of the Multivariate Adaptive Regression Splines [(MARS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_adaptive_regression_splines) algorithm?

Comment: (1) [RLink](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/RLink/guide/RLink.html) with one of the R packages? (2) Maybe http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/6905/